# Is it possible to convert a Win32 application project into a console application?

Tags: visual-studio, console

Is it possible to convert an existing visual studio project file that creates a Win32 application into a project file that creates a Win32 "Console" application? If so, how is this done? I've googled and found plenty of people doing the opposite, but none this way.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of work, how much Windows stuff is there - like forms and dialogs etc - you will need to rewrite all those. As far as programs startup is concerned - that should be trivial enough - just copy the files from a new command line app project. Oh yeah, and SUBSYSTEM switch.

Comment: Yah, Project + Properties, Application tab, Output Type = Console Application.  That gets you a console window.  As well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the linker level, the distinction is made with the [`/SUBSYSTEM` switch to the linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx). However, since there is so much other stuff built up around the type of project in Visual Studio, sometimes it's easiest to create a new console mode project, and add the existing code to the new project.

Comment: You can switch this fairly easily in the project properties: http://hdrlab.org.nz/articles/windows-development/changing-a-windows-app-to-a-console-app-in-visual-studio/. There's also a preprocessor definition: `_WINDOWS` which should be changed to `_CONSOLE` for both debug and release builds.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an automated way of that.  I think you can change all the project settings to make that switch.  But it would be tedious.  I believe it would be simpler to just create a new project and add the source files to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your version of visual studio. In the versions with XML project definitions, you can modify the XML. Heck, you might be able to do it with XSLT. In older version, you are better off creating a new project.

You should create two simple projects (one GUI, one Console) and compare the project definition XML files to see what needs to be done.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008. What specifically should I modify in the XML?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it depends on how the application was architected.  If the design is one that clearly separates business logic from the presentation, you may be able to extract the business logic code and classes into a separate library, if that hasn't yet been done.  Once that step is complete, you'll have to create a new API for that library, so that the console application (or any other application) can use it.

On the other hand, if the forms contain business logic, those processes are going to have to be pulled out into new, non-presentation classes and incorporated into your new libraries. As I said...possible, but could be a lot of work.